# unlist() gives unexpected results when used against a dataframe

Tags: r

I'm trying to determine the numerical order of values in a dataframe.  I've concatenated them into a single column, and the following seems to work on my test data:

```
(x = " 11 13 2")
(x = trimws(x))
(x2 = strsplit(x, " "))
(x2 = unlist(x2))
(x2 = as.numeric(x2))
x3 = sort(x2, index.return=TRUE)
x3$ix
```

When, however I come to run this against my dataframe I get the error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, y, value = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", : replacement has 756 rows, data has 252
3.
stop(sprintf(ngettext(N, "replacement has %d row, data has %d", "replacement has %d rows, data has %d"), N, nrows), domain = NA)
2.
`$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, y, value = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", ...
1.
`$<-`(`*tmp*`, y, value = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", ...
```

from the unlist() in:

```
df$y = strsplit(trimws(df$x), " ")
df$y = unlist(df$y)
```

I'm guessing that unlist() is acting upon the entire column, not just the cell?  Is there a better way of getting the output of strsplit() into a format suitable for further processing?

Example:

```
x = c( " 11, 13, 2", " 10 100, 11")
(df2 = data.frame(x))
(df2$y = strsplit(trimws(df2$x), " "))
df2
(df2$y2 = unlist(df2$y))
```

Comment: `df$y = strsplit(trimws(df$x), " ")` gives `y` as list column. What do you need `y` to be? You can use `df$y <- sapply(df$y, toString)` to get `y` as one-comma separated string. Can you give a reproducible example along with the expected output to make it clear?

Comment: @RonakShah MRE added.  Thanks!

Comment: Please add your expected output.

Comment: As explained about, the objective is (only) to run sort(..., index.return=TRUE) and insert the indices into the dataframe.  All the trimws/strsplit/unlist/as.numeric/... is just to get from a concatenation of numbers to something that sort doesn't choke on.

Comment: Yes, but as you must be aware that dataframe cannot have an unequal number of rows, `df2` has only 2 rows. `unlist(strsplit(trimws(df2$x), " "))` gives you a vector of length 6 so it is not clear to me which value out of those 6 you want to run `sort(..., index.return=TRUE)` and insert it into the dataframe.

Comment: Ah, understand.  I want to sort "11, 13, 2" to produce "3, 1, 2" and "10, 100, 11" to produce "1, 3, 2".  I think I just need to undo the first level of list in each cell, but even with recursion=false unlist is unlisting the entire column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the string on comma (`,`), convert the data to numeric and use `order` to get the order and collapse the data in one comma-separated string.

```
x = c( " 11, 13, 2", " 10 ,100, 11")
df2 = data.frame(x)
df2$y <- sapply(strsplit(trimws(df2$x), "\\s*,\\s*"), function(x) 
                toString(order(as.numeric(x))))

df2
#             x       y
#1    11, 13, 2 3, 1, 2
#2  10 ,100, 11 1, 3, 2
```

Using `sort(..., index.return = TRUE)`.

```
df2$y <- sapply(strsplit(trimws(df2$x), "\\s*,\\s*"), function(x)
               toString(sort(as.numeric(x), index.return=TRUE)$ix))
```

---

Using `lapply` will give `y` as list :

```
df2$y <- lapply(strsplit(trimws(df2$x), "\\s*,\\s*"), function(x) 
                order(as.numeric(x)))
```

Comment: very nice as always (Y) (+1)

Comment: That's perfect.  Many thanks @ronak. Forced me to go read up on apply() too.

Comment: @ronak Shah: I'm revisiting this as my requirements have changed a little: I now need to return not just the order, but also the sorted result as well. Am I correct in thinking that I will need to run a second sapply for this, as R can't return multiple results?

Comment: You can return multiple results as well. Perhaps, something like this would help. `t(sapply(strsplit(trimws(df2$x), "\\s*,\\s*"), function(x) 
  list(toString(order(as.numeric(x))), toString(sort(as.numeric(x))))))`

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this is what you want:

```
# Split Y: 
y <- strsplit(trimws(df$x), "\\W+")

# Roll-out, create index, rank values, row-wise concatenate: 
aggregate(.~idx,  within(data.frame(y = as.numeric(unlist(y)),
           idx = rep(1:nrow(df), sapply(y, length))),
           {rank = match(y, sort(y))}), toString)
```

Data:

```
x <- c( " 11, 13, 2", " 10 100, 11")
df <- data.frame(x = as.character(x))
```